# Как изменить UI виджета Autocomplete.IntentBuilder

Tags: android, google-places-api

надеюсь на вашу помощь.
В своем коде я использую виджет автозаполнения **Autocomplete.IntentBuilder** на весь экран, **Autocomplete.IntentBuilder** реализован согласно документации [Place Autocomplete](https://developers.google.com/places/android-sdk/autocomplete):

```
Intent intent = new Autocomplete.IntentBuilder(
            AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN, placeFields)
            .setTypeFilter(TypeFilter.CITIES)
            .build(this);

    startActivityForResult(intent, AUTOCOMPLETE_REQUEST_CODE);
```

Обшарил весь интернет **RU**, **EN** кроме изменения подсказки с помощью:

```
<string name="places_autocomplete_search_hint">SOME HINT TEXT</string>
```

не удалось найти хоть что-то по изменению внешнего вида **Autocomplete.IntentBuilder**, меня интересует, смена цвета подсказки, фона, стрелки, кнопки удаления (Х), курсора, чем больше информации тем лучше. И можно ли изменить отображение элементов при выборке, имею ввиду размер шрифта, цвет, форму ячеек в которой они находятся и т.п

Буду благодарен любой обратной связи

Answer (score 0):

Удалось узнать как поменять цвет заднего фона у **AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN**, у меня по умолчанию он был черного цвета. 
Оказывается он смотрит на **colorPrimary** в **style/AppTheme/colorPrimar**y, тут уже можно создать отельный стиль для **AutocompleteActivityMode.FULLSCREEN** либо использовать по умолчанию **AppTheme** и добавить его в файл манифеста нужного Activity, например:

```
<activity
        android:name=".activity.settings.SettingsActivity"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"/>
```

Так же цвет кнопки назад "**<**" устанавливается по умолчанию в зависимости от цвета **colorPrimary** "черный либо белый" насколько я понял

**Остальные вопросы все еще актуальны**